# "lift/raise all up to" or "lift/raise up all to"

Tags: word-order, phrasal-verbs, early-modern-english, old-english

I know the rule with phrasal verbs and pronouns is that

> If the object is a personal pronoun (me, you, him, us, etc.), we always put the pronoun before the particle:
>
> - Oh, I can’t ***lift you up*** any more. You’re too big now!
>
> Not: <del>I can’t lift up you any more.</del>

But I couldn't find such a rule with ***all***.

So I am wondering if there is any difference between

> He lifted/raised all up to a better understanding.

AND

> He lifted/raised up all to a better understanding.

Does ***all*** follow the same pattern? Why do both sentences sound right to me?

I tried [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A%20all%20up%20to%2Cup%20all%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bit%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthem%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bat%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27s%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bus%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bis%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwas%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bare%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwere%20all%20up%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cup%20all%20to%3B%2Cc0) but it didn't really address my question. Probably ***lifted/raised up all to*** is less common, but is it totally incorrect?

Edit: If *to raise someone up to a better understanding* is not idiomatic enough, [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raised%20up%20to%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Craised%20up%20to%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20heaven%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20deliver%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20its%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20him%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Craised%20up%20to%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20heaven%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20deliver%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20do%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20them%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20its%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Braised%20up%20to%20him%3B%2Cc0) suggests *to raise someone up to heaven*.
Edit 2: I work so often with English language as used by Shakespeare or the KJV Bible, that I forget to mention it in the tags. It seems the awkward word order ***raised up all to ...***, for example, was used in [older writings](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22raised%20up%20all%20to%22&safe=strict&biw=1760&bih=849&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02B1GrbThpC1N3BbVvi-hEB6z28VA%3A1624732812575&ei=jHTXYPXCIoKDhbIPx5-BMA&oq=%22raised%20up%20all%20to%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...24382.24382.0.25398.1.1.0.0.0.0.75.75.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.DiwQNG7kwzA).

Comment: lifted or raised up "to a better understanding" is not idiomatic. Generally, lifted and raised up as used with something like "a better understanding of something" would take an object: lifted the audience up.

Comment: **All** is the object here. I agree my example is not the most idiomatic. I will try to find a better one.

Comment: "lifted them all up to a better understanding" would be idiomatic.

Comment: "we raised everyone up"

Comment: @Lambie Yes, correct, I would say that too. But I am not trying to find an alternative. I am trying to figure out the correct use of **all**.

Comment: GArthurBrown has given that to you: lift + indirect object + all + up

Comment: @Lambie Oh, I was not aware that his utterances had the authority of "commonly reliable resources". And it is **direct object**, not indirect.

Comment: Oops, yes. Direct. You want an answer, he gave you one. I agree with him. And this question is really not good for this site. So, we are just being nice.

Comment: 'All' is rarely used 'after' a transitive MWV (and I'm not sure _lift up_  = lift in the physical sense qualifies as a MWV in any case). With the more obvious candidate _put down_ (= dis/s), 'He puts all down' sounds ridiculously old-fashioned. 'He puts down everybody' (stressed) and 'He puts everybody down' are both available. I can't think of a MWV where 'all' really works in either position. 'Them all' etc yes, but that changes the question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry for my ignorance, but what do you mean by MWV? And how can we explain this surprising [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=raised+all+up%2C+raised+up+all%2C+lift+all+up%2C+lift+up+all&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Craised%20all%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craised%20up%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clift%20all%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clift%20up%20all%3B%2Cc0) which gives preference to **lift up all** and **raised up all**? It just leaves me wondering.

Comment: The term 'phrasal verb' has so many different definitions that it's unhelpful (certainly without it's being defined every time someone uses it). MWV = multi-word verb, a lexeme used as a verb but containing more than one orthographic word (and not obvious compounds such as 'hang-glide'). Check here on ELU, and Claridge's work. //// As for the Ngrams: **check actual examples for false positives**. I have done; there's not much else.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, maybe it is safer to call it a multi-word verb. I do think though that people do use "[raise up all to](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22raised+up+all+to%22&safe=strict&biw=1760&bih=849&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02B1GrbThpC1N3BbVvi-hEB6z28VA%3A1624732812575&ei=jHTXYPXCIoKDhbIPx5-BMA&oq=%22raised+up+all+to%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...24382.24382.0.25398.1.1.0.0.0.0.75.75.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.DiwQNG7kwzA)", even if rarely. So it is not completely incorrect then?

Comment: You haven't included an 'Old English' or 'Early Modern English' tag, so I'd say 'archaic' at best. And do check; Matthew Henry has '... He raised up all believers to ...'. The quantifier usage (all + N) is very different. // 'He raised up all to the Last Day' is a single example, and archaic.

Comment: *All* is not a personal pronoun. Put it where you want — before or after the **particle**. _Put **on** shoes. Put shoes **on**._